# How to make REST calls to Azure Pipelines from c#

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

From c# code, I want to call Azure Devops Pipeline Url and get the job/build ids for that url. And then get the result if the job/build succeds/fail.
How to make REST call from c# code my Azure pipelines (I have the pipeline url)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [sample through HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#assemble-the-request). Additionally, you can use [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/16.199.0-preview) and `BuildHttpClient.GetBuildsAsync`: [the example is here](https://github.com/ashamrai/TFRestApi/blob/master/20.TFRestApiAppExploreBuildDefinitions/TFRestApiApp/Program.cs).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do authentication for Azure DevOps API.

1. Private PAT
2. Environment Variable: System.AccessToken

For PAT you can review [Shamrai Aleksander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8235971/shamrai-aleksander)'s code, if you want to call Azure DevOps API in your pipeline, you can conside use System.AccessToken.

Here is Powershell Script for your reference, the field of Authorization is different.

```
function Http-Request {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string] $SystemToken
    )
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($SystemToken)) {
        $pat = 'YOUR_PAT'
        $username = 'YOUR_USERNAME'
        $auth = '{0}:{1}' -f $username, $pat
        $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($auth)
        $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
        $auth = 'Basic ' + $encoded
    } else {
        $auth = 'Bearer ' + $SystemToken
    }
    $headers = @{
      'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
      'Authorization' = $auth
    }

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Http Request:'$Url
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Get -Headers $headers
    Write-Host ($reponse | Format-List | Out-String)
    return $response
}
```